# Can program be used to simplify algebraic complex expressions?

Tags: computational-mathematics, programming

I have several expressions of this kind  $$
\frac{p_1(1+|p_1|^2)}{(1-|p_1|^2)^2}-\frac{(1-|p_1|^2)p_2(1+p_2\overline{p_1})}{(1-\overline{p_1}p_2)|1-p_1\overline{p_2}|^2}\ .$$
Does there exists a program/application that can simplify this kind of expression like making common denominators.

Of course, one can do this computation. But it would be more interesting if there is a program that can simplify this kind of calculation without losing too much time...